# Cannot connect to wireless after running command

Tags: networking, wireless

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv iwldvm
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

I did the following commands that I read in a thread in this forum in order to resolve my wireless connection getting lost and now I cannot connect my laptop to my wireless connection at all. Please help me solve this issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to remove the file you created - with `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following commands to reverse what you did before:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwldvm
```

Then

`sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

and remove

> options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

from the bottom of the file. Save and close.

Comment: @TheodorosProtoulis You should also check the contents of `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` - if you have followed Tom's answer *and* done what you have shown above, the last two lines of the file will be `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` and `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=0`.  You should consider editing the file to remove both lines.

Comment: @CharlesGreen, good point, updated answer.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Did this as well. Thank you guys!